# Is it ok that Flanneld is listening on public interface udp port 8472?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, flannel, etcd3, flanneld

Security-wise, is it OK, that `flanneld` is listening on the public interface `udp` port `8472`?

Normally `kubernetes` nodes live in the *cloud*, hidden behind dozens of firewalls, they mostly operate in their local virtual network and only expose ports to the public, if administrator approves them manually.

But here I have a `bare-metal` server which is directly connected to the internet and I'm not sure if I should add firewall rules to block connections from the outside (default `fw` policy is `ACCEPT`).

For instance, I've configured `etcd3` to listen for client connections on `127.0.0.1`, furthermore clients must authenticate themselves with `tls` certificates. However `flannel` doesn't seem to have any authentication/authorization mechanism.

I understand that `flanneld` operates in the [Transport Layer](https://coreos.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/osi-model-clustering.png). Therefore it has information from the previous. 
So would it try drop any connection from the IPs, which are not in `etcd`?

For now my final intent is to create a *single-node* `kubernetes` “cluster”.